# Можно ли выразиться так?

Tags: грамотная-речь

Я бы хотела рассказать о русских суевериях в кикимору

Comment: Можно так: Я бы хотела рассказать о русских суевериях, связанных с кикиморой.

Answer (score 2):

"русских" - не то слово, путается с национальностью. "я бы" - не самая удачная конструкция. суеверия - тоже лучше не употреблять, потому что сразу слово несет негативный характер по отношению к пусть и языческим, но все-таки ритуалам - лучше *поверья*. Для тех кто верит в кикимору - это не предрассудок, а часть культурного взаимодействия с миром духов. Так что лучше: **я хочу рассказать о поверьях наших предков связанных с кикиморой.**

суеверия - это когда человек верит в чёрную кошку, что она дорогу перебежала, больше связано с удачей-неудачей, что-то более современное и больше он ничего не может сказать по сути, кроме того, что плохо, нужно плевать через плечо, весьма обрывочное знание. Вот чем чёрная кошка виновата, что она чёрная? И что более важно, чёрная кошка таки реальна, у неё даже хозяева могут быть.

духовный мир - это не обязательно суеверие, скорее всего, что не суеверья. Для веры в кикимору были основания, другое дело, что люди не всё понимали так, как современный человек, но это не значит, что они прямо тупыми были и верили всему на слово. Да и в лес они ходили, не смотря на то, что там кикимора, или леший, или водяной - но выдумывали правила поведения в лесу, которые часто были вполне себе разумны и обоснованы выживанием и тп. Другое дело что обосновывали они их не с точки зрения уже знания, а с точки зрения понятия о духовном мире и взаимодействия с ним. А в современном мире и веру в бога можно назвать суеверием, если не разбираться...

Даль ["О поверьях, суеверьях и предрассудках русского народа"](https://rodnovery.ru/images/knigi/dal-o-poveryakh-sueveriyakh-predrassudkakh.pdf):

> Поверьем называем мы вообще всякое укоренившееся в народе мнение или
> понятие, без разумного отчета в основательности его. Из этого следует, что поверье
> может быть истинное и ложное; в последнем случае оно называется собственно
> суеверием или, по новейшему выражению, предрассудком. Между этими двумя
> словами разницы мало; предрассудок есть понятие более тесное и относится
> преимущественно к предостерегательным, суеверным правилам, что, как и когда
> делать или не делать. Из этого усматривается, еще в третьем значении, важность предмета, о коем мы говорим; он дает нам полную картину жизни и быта известного народа.

Так что можно даже немного расширить: **я хочу рассказать о поверьях наших предков (или русского народа)**... далее можно из Даля рассказать, что такое поверье (мнение или понятие, а только не правило), а делее уже переходить непосредственно к кикиморе, а эта часть будет как вступление.

Comment: Отличный, образцовый ответ. Приятно видеть что-то подобное. Спасибо вам

Answer (score 1):

"Суеверие" не употребляется с предлогом "в." Допустимый вариант: "Я бы хотела рассказать о русских суевериях, связанных с кикиморами."